# How to import same module name from above directory

Tags: python, python-import

```
base
 - a.py 
 child1
   - __init__.py
   - a.py 
   child2
     - __init__.py
     - a.py 
     child3
       - __init__.py
       - a.py
```

I have a project structure like above. Base directory do not have a `__init__.py`. Inside `a.py` module of `child3` directory, I want to import a function named `get_version_no()` that is in `a.py` module of `base` directory.

If I try to do something like this `from a import get_version_no` it gives error that `get_version_no()` is not found in the module. I think it looks in the current module i.e in `a.py of child3` since the name of both module is same.

So how can I do the import?

Comment: Do you mean you cannot add \__init\__.py into base directory? If so, you cannot use 'import' method.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from a import *
```

Or

```
from ... import a
```

Comment: then you can try something like `from ... import a` this might work.

Comment: dots are used to go to upper levels, in this case three levels up